JSPDF multiplies the margin established on each page
JSPDF multiplies the margin established on each page, for example if I put 40 at the top, then on each page it increases 40 more.
my code:
 y = ((doc.getNumberOfPages() - 1) * doc.internal.pageSize.height);
            console.log('doc.internal.pageSize.height: ' + doc.internal.pageSize.height, 'doc.getNumberOfPages(): ' + doc.getNumberOfPages(), 'Y:' + y);
           
            await doc.html(content, {
                width: 500,
                windowWidth: 700,
                margin: [40, 40, 40, 40],
                y,
                autoPaging: 'text',            });

            if( contCursos < idCursos.length ){
                doc.addPage();
            }

I want the same top margin on all pages
thank you!
